# how to use oauth from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth

I am working to create a WP plugin, and I need to connect to an external service using OAuth. I wanted to know if wordpress already include a OAuth client API or if I should use some external library, or if you can point me to what is the best practice in that case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the WP REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server from here https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1

Here a Tutorial to install OAuth for the WP API https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-api-and-oauth-using-wordpress-without-wordpress/

Comment: but, is this a plugin? I wouldn't ask the users to install a plugin to use my plugin...

Comment: just to clarify, I need to create a plugin that use an external service, not the other way round...

Comment: okay, any application like facebook, twitter ... have his own oauthclass! sry, i dont know a external libaray, i have only this link, perhaps this will help you to move forward.   [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/oauth-php/wikis/ConsumerHowTo.wiki#Two-legged_OAuth)